# How to remove white screen on every navigation in Cordova app

Tags: cordova

I've created a cordova application from my web app based on html, javascript. Everything works fine except the navigations, My Web app was not a single page application and in response to navigating to a link, my cordova app shows white screen for a split screen and then loads my page content. Some idea how to remove that white screen? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some hints for you:

1. put your current a.html inside a div with id=divCurPage.
2. create another div with id=divNextPage and make it invisible.
3. Use jquery to load b.html into divNextPage, this jquery load function contains a callback function, which will only be run after b.html load completed.
4. Inside this callback function:

divCurPage.innerhtml = divNextPage.innerhtml

5. pls. note that any js to be run inside b.html, should not put inside b.html   Put them in separate js and include these js files inside a.html.  Because jquery load function delete all js inside the html file loaded.

ok, you just turn your multiple html pages app into an SPA.

Comment: Seems like I was using <iframe> which was causing the issue, As soon as I removed the <iframe> the white flicker disappears.

Comment: try Not to use separate html, e.g. a.html and b.html both contain dynamic contents pushed by a socket.io server.  If you use a hyperlink to change page, the socket disconnects on every change.  That's why SPA is so important in hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the white screen flickering, I removed the ifrmaes from my code and set entry point for the project to my HTML file and everything works fine as expected.